# What is a good server I can use for uploading / storing videos?

Tags: server, video-streaming

I am making a video sharing app for IOS and eventually will be adding it to the google play store too.

I was previously using firebase for my server to upload videos to, but I ran into some problems and firebase doesn't allow you to upload videos while your app is in the background (at least I couldn't figure it out). So I am switching servers and I would like to get some recommendations from you guys.

**Question:**

What is a good server / API that I can use to upload and store a lot of videos until they need to be downloaded when a user wants to watch one of them? Videos will be about 10 minutes on average, but they could be as long as 24 hours.

Comment: Instead of common storage cloud service like AWS S3 or Google Firebase for file management, a dedicated and professional video cloud platform is better solution, such as [Tencent](https://intl.cloud.tencent.com/products/vod) video cloud or others, because VoD is not equal to file management(Vod need transcoding, delivery, transmux, DRM, streaming, player SDK etc), while your video sharing app is actually a VoD service at the backend view.

Comment: @Winlin thanks for the response this is super helpful! Do you have any other suggestions besides Tencent cloud? I am having a hard time finding more options by searching google.